# how to customise dynatree image?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dynatree

I am using jquery dynatree plugin.(http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) I am using its vista theme,I want instead of small triangle on the left(node expander symbol) of each folder,my custom image (a plus ) symbol to come. More over I want to remove folder image and no image should be used in place of folder image..
is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the image used in the CSS file for the images. We replaced the folder icons with nicer looking ones, and the tree lines to windows 7 style arrows indicating whether the tree was expanded or not.

The image we edited was icons.gif.

Just make sure you align the replacement images in the same place to avoid changing all the background positions in the css file.