# How to use jquery-ui icons in dynatree

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, icons, dynatree

I want to embed jquery-ui icons in the jquery dynatree plugin.

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html

There is an icons.gif based solution here.
[how to customise dynatree image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447483/how-to-customise-dynatree-image)

But can I use jquery-ui icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The successor of Dynatree ([Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree)) allows this:

```
<li data-iconclass="ui-icon ui-icon-heart">'iconclass' is directly added to the image &lt;span>, so jQuery stock icons may be used
```

See here for a [demo](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-theming.html)